# Get current culture in MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a small app that contains errormessages in database, so they'll be easy to edit etc from a webpage.

So my question is what do I need to put in my class, the "...typeof(MyCustomErrorApp)" to get the current culture? What needs to be derived (?) from etc?

/Lasse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET [resource provider is extensible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx). So you could write your custom `ResourceProviderFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about validation attributes - those are loading resources from static class using reflection. You can simply target any class with static properties:

```
public class DBErrorResources
{
    public static string Required
    {
        get { return DB.FetchErrorMesssage(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture); }
    }
}
```